# Angular2 testcase shows No provider for NgControl

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, angular, karma-jasmine

`ng test` shows the below error but it works as expected in reality.

```
Error: Template parse errors:
    No provider for NgControl ("
      <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label">Location</label>
        [ERROR ->]<select class="selectpicker" *ngIf="locations" data-style="btn btn-primary btn-round" title="Select A"): VehicleFormComponent@27:4
    No provider for NgControl ("  <div class="form-group label-floating">
        <label class="control-label">Is Available</label>
        [ERROR ->]<md-slide-toggle [(ngModel)]="isAvailable" color="primary" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
       "): VehicleFormComponent@41:4 in src/test.ts (line 25739)
    Expected undefined to be truthy.
```

I think it's mainly because of adding `[ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"` in a custom tag.

Comment: Did you add reference to "FormsModule" in your TestBed module?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/48156981/3894981

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Did you add reference to "FormsModule" in your TestBed module?

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [ FormsModule ]
})
.compileComponents();
```

Comment: did you able to reproduce this error `PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0): Executed 39 of 65 (1 FAILED) (0 secs / 1.296 secs)
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Linux 0.0.0) VehicleFormComponent should create FAILED
 get
 LocationsService@webpack:///src/app/shared/services/locations.service.ts:9:4173 <- src/test.ts:53695:4196
 getInternal`

Comment: Yes, I had this error. Try to add also `RouterTestingModule` into your TestBed imports. Import from `import {RouterTestingModule} from "@angular/router/testing";`. Let me know if it help.

Comment: No, it not this case. I had `LocationStrategy` error.  But seems it's some assert failed only, not compilation problems. No?

Comment: yep. only on running testcase

Comment: Try run your tests from IDE (e.g. WebStorm) - it shows proper stacktrace if exception occurs. Because error not clear - it can instantiate service as I understand. But no more info (

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134690/discussion-between-avinash-raj-and-vadimb).

Comment: In case it helps anyone else... I was using a reactive form and therefore had to import the ReactiveFormsModule rather than the FormsModule. Because I was setting my form control on a mat-radio-group I also had to import MatRadioModule.

Answer (score 3):

If anybody else comes here, maybe this will help. I was missing the optional decorator in the constructor:

```
  constructor(@Optional() @Self() public ngControl: NgControl) {}
```

Comment: But why is @Optional() necessary in the first place?

Comment: @dude You can have a look at a good article related here: https://medium.com/frontend-coach/self-or-optional-host-the-visual-guide-to-angular-di-decorators-73fbbb5c8658