# ERROR in : No provider for NgControl Angular AOT

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli

I am trying to implement a custom ControlValueAccessor as Kara Erickson recommended on last Angular Connect https://youtu.be/CD_t3m2WMM8?t=20m22s . To pass the validity state from the parent component to the child one.

app.component.html:

```
<app-country-select ngModel="model" name="country-select"></app-country-select>
```

country-select.component.html:

```
<select [formControl]="controlDir.control" #select placeholder="Country" i18n-placeholder (click)="onTouched()"
        (change)="onChange($event.value)" [required]="required">
  <option value="at">Austria</option>
  <option value="au">Australia</option>
</select>
```

country-select.component.ts:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-country-select',
    templateUrl: './country-select.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./country-select.component.scss'],
})
export class CountrySelectComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {

    @Input() required = false;

    @ViewChild('select') select: HTMLSelectElement;

    onChange: (value: any) => void;
    onTouched: () => void;

    constructor(@Self() public controlDir: NgControl) {
      controlDir.valueAccessor = this;

    }
...
}
```

The full code lives here: https://github.com/maksymzav/ngcontrol .

The code works perfectly when running it in the JIT mode. I guess because in runtime it does know with which control it is used: NgModel, or FormControlName, or FormControlDirective.
But when I run an AOT build with `ng build --prod` it fails with message

> ERROR in : No provider for NgControl ("[ERROR ->]<app-country-select></app-country-select>")

Does anyone know how to make this build successful? Thank you.

Comment: You probably forgot to wrap the generated html in a form tag.

Comment: See as well this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37284763/using-ngcontrol-caused-error-no-provider-for-controlcontainer

Comment: @Igor, do you mean to wrap the code in app.component.html into the form tag? It won't help, unfortunately.

Comment: @lemmingworks, the post you're writing about is about angular2 way of using forms, when there were no modules. I imported both FormsModule and ReactiveFormsModule, so all directives should be in.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can add [`@Optional()`](https://angular.io/api/core/Optional) decorator to your `controlDir`.

> A parameter metadata that marks a dependency as optional. Injector 
>   provides null if the dependency is not found.

In my case, that solved the "No provider" error and I was able to successfully compile the project.

Example:

```
constructor(
  @Optional() // Add this decorator
  @Self()
  public controlDir: NgControl,
  private stripe: StripeService,
  private cd: ChangeDetectorRef
) {
  // Better to add some checks here since controlDir can be null
  if (controlDir) {
    controlDir.valueAccessor = this;
  }
}
```

Comment: For me this happened even without aot build, just in a normal serve. When i added @Optional() decorator, it says "Cannot read property 'control' of null". How can i resolve this?