# Getting No provider for NgControl Error after adding ReactiveFormsModule to my angular 4 app

Tags: angular

I am getting this error - "Template parse errors: No provider for NgControl"

```
 The error comes from this line of code

 --> <select (ngModel)="currencies" (ngModelChange)="showPurchase($event)" class="annka-center" name="curencies">
       <option *ngFor="let money of currencies; let i = index" (ngValue)="money" (click)="showPurchase(money)"> {{money.Currency}} </option>
 </select>
```

The above code worked smoothly till i added ReactiveFormsModule to my app.

I tried the solution here

[ERROR in : No provider for NgControl Angular AOT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47886424/error-in-no-provider-for-ngcontrol-angular-aot?noredirect=1&lq=1)

but that didnt work for me. I am using Angular 4.

Comment: Why are you using `(ngModel)`?

Comment: @yurzui pointed the issue : you're using `ngModel` and `ngModelChange`, which are part of `FormsModule`, while you imported `ReactiveFormsModule`

Comment: WOW!  Good Catch!!  I just had the same thing happen.  The only thing I had to do differently is also import `FormsModule` and it fixed it.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Should be

```
<select [(ngModel)]="currencies" (ngModelChange)="showPurchase($event)" class="annka-center" name="curencies">
       <option *ngFor="let money of currencies; let i = index" (ngValue)="money" (click)="showPurchase(money)"> {{money.Currency}} </option>
 </select>
```

Also make sure you import `FormsModule` inside the `app.module.ts` under imports

```
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

    @NgModule({
        imports: [
             FormsModule  
             ReactiveFormsModule     
        ]
```

Comment: I needed to import ReactiveFormsModule.

Comment: Just to clarify, the answer should also have `ReactiveFormsModule` in the array of imports.

Answer (score 25):

I too got this error because I forgot to add the `formControlName` directive to my form control in the template, by which I mean:

```
<input formControlName="firstName" />
```

Comment: I maked typo in name
wrote formControllerName
instead formControlName

Answer (score 7):

I got this error because i forgot to add `[(ngModel)]` on my input element.

```
<input [(ngModel)]="firstName/>
```

Answer (score 3):

I faced same issue on angular 10.x version, I have to add CommonModule inside app.module.ts.

```
import {CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
         CommonModule,
         FormsModule      
    ]
```

Answer (score 3):

To resolve this error, I imported **5 modules** in my app.module.ts ( You can import in the relevant component.module.ts, if you don't prefer to add it in app.module.ts):

1. ReactiveFormsModule
2. FormsModule
3. HttpClientModule
4. BrowserAnimationsModule
5. MatSelectModule

How to import:

```
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { MatSelectModule } from '@angular/material';    
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
         ReactiveFormsModule,
         FormsModule,
         MatSelectModule, 
         HttpClientModule, 
         BrowserAnimationsModule
    ]
// rest of your code
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to use a form control **without a form** you can easily confuse `formControlName` with `formControl`

```
copyTo = new FormControl(null, {
  validators: Validators.required
});
```

wrong

```
<lib-input-select [formControlName]="'copyTo'" />
```

Correct

```
<lib-input-select [formControl]="copyTo" />
```