# No provider for NgControl found in NodeInjector

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ng-modules

Even though I imported `FormsModule`, `ReactiveFormsModule` in **app.module.ts** always I get
`No provider for NgControl found in NodeInjector.` error

**home.page.html**

```
<ion-content style="max-height: 160px;">
  <form [formGroup]="todo" (ngSubmit)="logForm()">
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Todo</ion-label>
      <ion-input type="text" formControlName="title"></ion-input>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Description</ion-label>
      <ion-textarea formControlName="description"></ion-textarea>
    </ion-item>
    <button ion-button type="submit" [disabled]="!todo.valid">Submit</button>
  </form>
</ion-content>
```

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
....
  imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule, FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
...
```

What may be the reason behind this?

Comment: add `ReactiveFormsModule ` in homepage modules file

Comment: @RaviAshara it solved the issue. Thnx.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting No provider for NgControl Error after adding ReactiveFormsModule to my angular 4 app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48525216/getting-no-provider-for-ngcontrol-error-after-adding-reactiveformsmodule-to-my-a)

Comment: @RameshRajendran No, that's what I did first. I've already mentioned that I added `ReactiveFormsModule` in app.module.ts

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add `ReactiveFormsModule`  in `home.page.module.ts` file