# No provider for NgControl found in NodeInjector. how to get rid from this error?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-errorhandler

[image: error image]

I am facing this issue, I am searching a lot but nothing works.

Please suggest to me, how to solve this.

I have added this to the application module file.
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms' and include in import

But it is already added.
Please suggest something which actually works.

Comment: [Checked this???](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48525216/681929)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using reactive forms? You have to import ReactiveFormsModule too