# Angular2+ testcase shows No provider for NgControl

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript, testbed

I am trying to test an angular component which has quite a lot of dependencies. But the test case expect(component).toBeTruthy(); fails with the Error: No Provider for NgControl. The full error message is the following:

```
Chrome 66.0.3359 (Mac OS X 10.13.4) configurator component unit tests has a configurator FAILED
                    </div>
                    [ERROR ->]<form *ngIf="!loading" class="form" [formGroup]="options">
                        <mat-form-field>
                    <form *ngIf="!loading" class="form" [formGroup]="options">
                        <mat-form-field>
                        <mat-form-field>
                            [ERROR ->]<input matInput #input placeholder="{{'customer.lastname' | translate}}" formControlName="lastname">
                        <mat-form-field>
                            [ERROR ->]<input matInput placeholder="{{'customer.email' | translate}}" formControlName="email">
error properties: Object({ ngSyntaxError: true, ngParseErrors: [ No provider for ControlContainer ("
                            <input matIn"): ng:///DynamicTestModule/CustomerComponent.html@12:5, No provider for NgControl ("
                            [ERROR ->]<input matInput #input placeholder="{{'customer.firstname' | translate}}" formControlName="firstname""): ng:///DynamicTestModule/CustomerComponent.html@14:7, No provider for NgControl ("
"): ng:///DynamicTestModule/CustomerComponent.html@18:7, No provider for NgControl ("
                            <mat-e"): ng:///DynamicTestModule/CustomerC ...
Error: Template parse errors:
    at <Jasmine>
    at syntaxError node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js:486:22)
    at TemplateParser.webpackJsonp../node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js.TemplateParser.parse node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js:24674:1)
    at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp../node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._parseTemplate node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js:34629:1)
    at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp../node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileTemplate node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js:34604:1)
    at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js:34505:48
    at <Jasmine>
    at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp../node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileComponents node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js:34505:1)
    at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js:34393:1
    at Object.then node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js:475:33)
    at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp../node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileModuleAndAllComponents node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js:34391:1)
Expected undefined to be truthy.
    at <Jasmine>
    at UserContext.<anonymous> src/app/configurator/configurator.component.spec.ts:90:26)
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:388:1)
    at ProxyZoneSpec.webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:128:1)
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:387:1)
Chrome 66.0.3359 (Mac OS X 10.13.4): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) (0 secs / 0 secs)
 Chrome 66.0.3359 (Mac OS X 10.13.4) configurator component unit tests has a configurator FAILED
                    </div>
                    [ERROR ->]<form *ngIf="!loading" class="form" [formGroup]="options">
                        <mat-form-field>
                    <form *ngIf="!loading" class="form" [formGroup]="options">
                        <mat-form-field>
                        <mat-form-field>
                            [ERROR ->]<input matInput #input placeholder="{{'customer.lastname' | translate}}" formControlName="lastname">
                        <mat-form-field>
                            [ERROR ->]<input matInput placeholder="{{'customer.email' | translate}}" formControlName="email">
error properties: Object({ ngSyntaxError: true, ngParseErrors: [ No provider for ControlContainer ("
                            <input matIn"): ng:///DynamicTestModule/CustomerComponent.html@12:5, No provider for NgControl ("
                            [ERROR ->]<input matInput #input placeholder="{{'customer.firstname' | translate}}" formControlName="firstname""): ng:///DynamicTestModule/CustomerComponent.html@14:7, No provider for NgControl ("
"): ng:///DynamicTestModule/CustomerComponent.html@18:7, No provider for NgControl ("
                            <mat-e"): ng:///DynamicTestModule/CustomerC ...
Error: Template parse errors:
    at <Jasmine>
    at syntaxError node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js:486:22)
    at TemplateParser.webpackJsonp../node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js.TemplateParser.parse node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js:24674:1)
    at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp../node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._parseTemplate node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js:34629:1)
    at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp../node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileTemplate node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js:34604:1)
    at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js:34505:48
    at <Jasmine>
    at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp../node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileComponents node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js:34505:1)
    at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/webpack:/node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js:34393:1
    at Object.then node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js:475:33)
    at JitCompiler.webpackJsonp../node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js.JitCompiler._compileModuleAndAllComponents node_modules/@angular/compiler/esm5/compiler.js:34391:1)
Expected undefined to be truthy.
    at <Jasmine>
    at UserContext.<anonymous> src/app/configurator/configurator.component.spec.ts:90:26)
    at ZoneDelegate.webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:388:1)
    at ProxyZoneSpec.webpackJsonp../node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js.ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke node_modules/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:128:1)
Chrome 66.0.3359 (Mac OS X 10.13.4): Executed 1 of 1 (1 FAILED) ERROR (0.838 secs / 0 secs)
```

I already included stuff like FormsModule and RouterTestingModule but it still does not work.

```
describe('configurator component unit tests', () => {
  let configurator: ConfiguratorComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ConfiguratorComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        ProductsService,
        OrdersService,
        UdiService,
        CustomersService,
        TranslateService,
        {
          provide: ActivatedRoute, useValue: {
            params: Observable.of({ id: 'test' })
          }
        }
      ],
      declarations: [
        ConfiguratorComponent,
        LoginComponent,
        ForgotpasswordComponent,
        ResetpasswordComponent,
        RegisterComponent,
        ContactComponent,
        CustomerComponent,
        HomeComponent,
        PageNotFoundComponent],
      imports: [
        FormsModule,
        CommonModule,
        TranslateModule,
        MatProgressSpinnerModule,
        MatButtonModule,
        ElementsModule,
        ViewerModule,
        OrdersModule,
        RouterTestingModule],
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
    }).compileComponents(
    ).then(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ConfiguratorComponent);
    configurator = fixture.componentInstance;
    });
  }));
```

So I am clearly missing some module but which one? I am fairly new to angular test bed.

angular version: 5.2
karma version: 2.0.2
karma-jasmine version: 1.1.1

Oh, and it might be a duplicate of that one but since this one never got answered after the suggestions I added I thought it is okay. :S 
[Angular2 testcase shows No provider for NgControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42002079/angular2-testcase-shows-no-provider-for-ngcontrol)

Comment: You are missing `ReactiveFormsModule`

Comment: wow thanks :O that did it :D

Comment: @MikeTung do you perhaps also know whats causing the new StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[TranslateService -> TranslateStore]:  "No provider for TranslateStore" Error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To help consolidate answers: Initially you were missing `ReactiveFormsModule`.

To answer your second question, you need to provide the `TranslateStore` in your providers array for the Testbed

Comment: you sir are my hero :D

Comment: glad I could help :)

Comment: import { TranslateStore } from '@ngx-translate/core';
has no exported member 'TranslateStore'.
:O where should I export the TranslateStore from?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to import FormsModule and or ReactiveFormsModule, in TestBed.

```
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

TestBed.configureTestingModule ({
    imports: [FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule]
});
```

*Note:* FormsModule is used for template-driven-forms and ReactiveFormsModule is used for reactive-driven-forms.